# How to fix: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR)

Tags: php, html, boolean

Does anybody know why I get this error message?
This is my code: (the error is on line 23)

```
<?php

$filnavn="student.txt"; /*filnavn angitt*/ 

$navn=$_POST["navn"]; 


      $filoperasjon="r"; 
      print("Følgende studenter er registrert); <br/>"); 

      $fil=fopen($filnavn, $filoperasjon); /* fil åpnet*/ 

      while ($linje=fgets($fil)) /*en linje lest fra fil*/ 
        {
        if ($linje !="") 

        {
          $del=explode(";", $linje); 
20.          $brukernavn=$del[0];  
21.         $fornavn=$del[1]; 
22.         $etternavn=$del[2]; 
21.
22.    if (strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($brukernavn)) || strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($fornavn) || 23.strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($etternavn)))
24.         /* brukernavn,fornavn eller etternavn er lik mottat navn */ 
25.         {
26.             print("$brukernavn $fornavn $etternavn <br/>"); 
27.          }
28.      }
29.     }
30.        fclose ($fil); /* filen lukket */ 
31. ?>
```

Comment: Better balance your parenthesis in the `if`.

Comment: Should be `if (strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($brukernavn) || strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($fornavn) || strtoupper($navn)==strtoupper($etternavn)){` you have extra `)`s... or syntactically maybe trying to achieve other logic though?